# Fetching data using ajax and inserting in html using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have fetched data from my `php/products.php` file using ajax and have a `html` file that I have already styled. How can I insert the data I have fetched from the `products.php` file in the `html` page?

Most of my search results are based on jQuery.

The containers I've used are the containers styled in the `css` file.

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <header class="header">
         <center>
            <h1>Products</h1>
         </center>
      </header>
      <hr>
      <div id="products" class="products"></div>

      <button id="loadButton" class="btn">Load more</button>
   </div>
```

The JS

```
var loadBtn = document.getElementById('loadButton');

loadBtn.addEventListener('click', fetchProducts);

function fetchProducts() {

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

   xhr.open('GET', `php/products.php?${q}`, true);

   xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status == 200) {
         var products = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

         var output, i;

         for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            output += `
                     <div id="pCard" class="p-card">
                           <p id="pName" class="p-name">${products[i].name}</p>
                           <p id="pAbout" class="p-about">${products[i].description}</p>
                     </div>
                     `;
         }

         console.log(products);

         document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = output;
      }
   }

   xhr.send();
}
```

The PHP

```
include 'config.inc.php';

$sqlFetch = "SELECT id,item_name,item_description FROM items ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlFetch);

$products = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($products);
```

I expect the code to parse the containers containing the product name and description to the products container in the HTML page. On clicking the `loadBtn` I want three more products to be loaded on the webpage Instead am getting an error from the console.

Comment: Try using `console.log(this.responseText)` in the onload function to check what the "JSON" looks like - seems to be no valid JSON. This can, for instance, occur when your PHP scripts prints an error message.

Comment: Found the error :) . Thanks to you @Kryptur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was at the `php/products.php?${q}` on the `JS` file.

I was also targeting `name` and `description` instead of `item_name` and `item_description`.

```
`
<div id="pCard" class="p-card">
  <p id="pName" class="p-name">${products[i].name}</p>
  <p id="pAbout" class="p-about">${products[i].description}</p>
</div>
`;
```